# How to make a table responsive by class name?

Tags: css

I have this media:

```
@media
only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
        display: block;
    }

    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    thead tr {
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
    }

    tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

    td {
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%;
    }

    td:before {
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px;
        left: 6px;
        width: 45%;
        padding-right: 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

}
```

This media affects all `table` elements. Now how can I use this media just on a table that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add class or id for your table you want. For example, I add `class="test"` to your table that you want. And your CSS like this

```
@media
only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    .test, .test thead, .test tbody, .test th, .test td, .test tr {
        display: block;
    }

    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    .test thead tr {
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
    }

    .test tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

    .test td {
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%;
    }

    .test td:before {
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px;
        left: 6px;
        width: 45%;
        padding-right: 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**CSS3 Media rule is just like another if condition in your CSS statement.**

Now, let's say you have a table with a class named 'myTable'.

*E.g.* You want to make class `myTable` width to be `500px` for **all** kind of device that has their screen width resolution *between `640px to 1024px`*, this is how you do it.

```
@media all and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 640px)  
{
   /* This is a comment, in the selector below you're setting
    * a width of all tables that have myTable in their class.
    */
   table.myTable
   {
      width: 500px;
   }
}
```

So, in the css statement above, you're basically saying `If the client uses any kind of device and have their width between 640px to 1024px, apply the rule as following`.

Or, you want to set `myTable` width to `500px` only to those who use **iPhone in landscaped position**. You may do;

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape)
{
   table.myTable
   {
      width: 500px;
   }
}
```

Reference: [CSS Media Query Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Then, let's use your media rule as a sample.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)
```

This is basically telling that to apply the wrapped CSS rules for

> Screens, tablets or smartphones which has screen width less than `760px` ***OR*** any device with their screen width between `768px to 1024px`.

You might also want to read [CSS Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)